# Move 0s to top of each column in a MxN array

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

I have a matrix of NxM (the dimensions are set by the user) and I want a function to move 0s to the top of each column, and leave the rest integers as they are. Look at the example:

Move 0s to the top of each column in a MxN array

[image]

After the movement of 0s I want to have:

[image]

Someone please correct my `zerototopMatrix` function below:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <time.h>

void printMatrix(int (*arr), int rows, int cols,int level)
{
    int i, j;

    printf("\n");
    printf("\n");

    printf("The matrix elements are:\n   ");
    for (i = 0; i < cols+level; i++) {
        printf("%d ", i+1);
    } 
    printf("\n");
    for (i = 0; i < (cols*2+1+level); i++) {
        printf("-");
    } 
    printf("-\n");
    for (i = 0; i < rows+level; i++) {
        printf("%d| ", i+1);
        for (j = 0; j < cols+level; j++) {
            printf("%d ", *(arr + i*cols + j)); 
        }     
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void zerototopMatrix(int (*arr), int rows, int cols,int level)
{
    int i, j;

    printf("\n");
    printf("\n");

    int count = 0,temp = 0;

    for (j = 0; j < cols+level; j++) {
        for (i = 0; i < rows+level; i++) {
            if (*(arr + i*cols + j)==0)
            {
                (*(arr + i*cols + j)= (*(arr + count*cols + j)));
                (*(arr + count*cols + j))=0;
                count++;
            }
        }     
    }
}

int main() { 

    int number;

    srand ( time(NULL) );
    int level = 0;

    int row,col,colors;
    int points = 0;


    printf("How many rows:\n");
    scanf("%d", &row);

    printf("How many columns:\n");
    scanf("%d", &col);

    printf("How many colors:\n");
    scanf("%d", &colors);

    int *arr = (int *)malloc(row * col * sizeof(int)); 
    int i, j; 

    for (i = 0; i < row+level; i++) 
        for (j = 0; j < col+level; j++) {
            number = rand() % colors ;
            *(arr + i*col + j) = number;   
        }

    printMatrix(arr, row, col,level);

    printf("\n\nMove 0s to top:\n");
    zerototopMatrix(arr, row, col,level);

    printMatrix(arr, row, col,level);

    free(arr); 
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Note that `int (*arr)` in the argument lists to the functions is semantically identical to `int *arr`.  The parentheses would be necessary if you had a pointer to an array such as  `int (*arr)[12]`, for example.

Comment: Note that `printf("\n");
    printf("\n");` could be changed to `printf("\n\n");` — Indeed `printf("\n");
    printf("\n");

    printf("The matrix elements are:\n");` could be changed to: 

    `printf("\n\nThe matrix elements are:\n");`

Comment: I also hope you only ever enter `0` for the level; you aren't allocating enough space to use larger values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be accomplished simply by moving non-zero elements to the bottom of the array, working from bottom to top for each column:

- Set a source index S and a destination index D to the bottom of the array.
- Iterate and decrement S until S would pass the top of the array:

  - If element S is not zero, copy element S to element D and decrement D.
- Iterate and decrement D until D would pass the top of the array:

  - Set element D to zero.

Code is:

```
void zeroToTopMatrix(int *arr, int rows, int cols, int level)
{
    //  Iterate through columns.
    for (int c = 0; c < cols + level; ++c)
    {
        //  Start destination index at bottom of column.
        int D = rows + level;

        //  Iterate source index backwards through column, skipping zeros.
        for (int S = rows + level - 1; 0 <= S; --S)
            if (arr[S*cols + c] != 0)
                arr[--D*cols + c] = arr[S*cols + c];

        //  Fill in top elements with skipped zeros.
        while (0 < D)
            arr[--D*cols + c] = 0;
    }
}
```

I have kept the `level` variable as in the original code, but it looks out of place and will likely break the code if it is non-zero.

Comment: Thank you Eric Postpischil!!

Answer (score 1):

My initial inclination was to create a temporary buffer to store all of the non-zero elements:

```
void zeroToTopMatrix(int *arr, int rows, int cols, int level) {
    int i, j;

    for (j = 0; j < cols + level; j++) {
        int tmp[rows];
        int tmpLen = 0;

        for (i = 0; i < rows + level; i++) {
            if (arr[i*cols+j]) {
                tmp[tmpLen++] = arr[i*cols+j];
            }
        }

        for (i = 0; i < rows - tmpLen; i++) {
            arr[i*cols+j] = 0;
        }

        for (int k = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            arr[i*cols+j] = tmp[k++];
        }
    }
}
```

But the proposal from Eric Postpischil is much smarter--move from the bottom to the top of each column, performing swaps as needed and padding the top out with zeroes. Here's the code:

```
void zeroToTopMatrix(int *arr, int rows, int cols, int level) {
    int i, j;

    for (j = 0; j < cols + level; j++) {
        int k = rows + level - 1;

        for (i = k; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (arr[i*cols+j]) {
                arr[k--*cols+j] = arr[i*cols+j];
            }
        }

        while (k >= 0) {
            arr[k--*cols+j] = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Here's a complete test:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <time.h>

void zeroToTopMatrix(int *arr, int rows, int cols, int level) {
    int i, j;

    for (j = 0; j < cols + level; j++) {
        int k = rows + level - 1;

        for (i = k; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (arr[i*cols+j]) {
                arr[k--*cols+j] = arr[i*cols+j];
            }
        }

        while (k >= 0) {
            arr[k--*cols+j] = 0;
        }
    }
}


void printMatrix(int *arr, int rows, int cols, int level) {
    int i, j;

    printf("\n");
    printf("\n");
    printf("The matrix elements are:\n   ");

    for (i = 0; i < cols + level; i++) {
        printf("%d ", i + 1);
    } 

    printf("\n");

    for (i = 0; i < (cols * 2 + 1 + level); i++) {
        printf("-");
    } 

    printf("-\n");

    for (i = 0; i < rows + level; i++) {
        printf("%d| ", i + 1);

        for (j = 0; j < cols + level; j++) {
            printf("%d ", *(arr + i * cols + j)); 
        }     

        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main() { 
    int i, j; 
    int number;
    int level = 0;
    int row, col, colors;
    int points = 0;

    srand(15/*time(NULL)*/);
    row = 5;
    col = 9;
    colors = 5;

    int *arr = malloc(row * col * sizeof(int)); 

    for (i = 0; i < row + level; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < col + level; j++) {
            number = rand() % colors;
            *(arr + i * col + j) = number;   
        }
    }

    printMatrix(arr, row, col, level);
    zeroToTopMatrix(arr, row, col, level);
    printMatrix(arr, row, col, level);

    free(arr); 
    return 0; 
}
```

Output:

```
The matrix elements are:
   1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
--------------------
1| 3 0 2 0 1 0 4 2 3
2| 3 3 2 4 4 0 0 4 2
3| 4 3 0 0 3 1 0 1 3
4| 1 0 3 0 0 0 4 0 3
5| 0 0 1 3 0 4 3 1 0


The matrix elements are:
   1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
--------------------
1| 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
2| 3 0 2 0 0 0 0 2 3
3| 3 0 2 0 1 0 4 4 2
4| 4 3 3 4 4 1 4 1 3
5| 1 3 1 3 3 4 3 1 3
```

A couple of additional tips:

- Sometimes pointer arithmetic is elegant, but it seems clearer to just use array indices in this case with the 2d array packed into 1d.
- No need to cast the result of `malloc` in C.

Comment: In every level the dimensions of the matrix should raise automtically by 1. So I have a variable called level. Originally set to 0 and if the user procceeds to next level, the matrix will "grow" 1 size larger in both directions. The level will be 1. The display of the matrix, and the "sorting of zeros" will have to run to a larger matrix...

Comment: OK--that seems easy enough to add yourself, or include code to use that so I can test a solution. Does this solve the problem?

Comment: Yes it does !!! Can I send you the whole code and a brief description of what I am trying to implement to your email or inbox?

Comment: Excellent. Do you need additional help with your code or are you just looking to share? Feel free to post a github link in this comment thread and I can take a look.

Comment: I need additional help, but if it is possible with you, I wouldn't like to post the whole problem and the code publicly...

Comment: There is no need for two passes over a column or a temporary array. Simply set a source index S and a destination index D to the bottom of the array. Iterate until S would pass the top of the array: { If element S is not zero, copy element S to element D and decrement D. Decrement S. } iterate until D would pass the top of the array: Set element D to zero.

Comment: OK I sent you an email!!